# Expected Identifier? What?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, block, objective-c-blocks

I have this property declared on a singleton:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onUpdate)();
```

After starting the singleton on a class I have these lines:

```
[self.singleton.onUpdate = ^{ 
  CGAffineTransform rot = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(angle));
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
      myself.object.transform = rot;
  }];
}];
```

I have an "expected identifier" error on this last line... what?

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extraneous pair of brackets surrounding your assignment statement. Remove.